# WP CLI info showing correct PHP binary but wrong version of PHP

Tags: php, wp-cli, apache

When a run a command such as `wp plugin update` I get the message:
"Your server is running PHP version 5.4.13 but WordPress 5.2.2 requires at least 5.6.20"

I don't even have PHP 5.4 installed in my server.

When I run `wp cli info` I get the following:

```
PHP binary: /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php
PHP version:    5.4.13
php.ini used:   /etc/php.ini
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I updated WP CLI to version 2.3 thinking maybe that would help but I get the same results.

Running CentOS 6 if that makes a difference.

Comment: What does `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php --version` return you?

Comment: @leymannx It shows PHP 7.2.22

Comment: And just `php --version`?

Comment: @leymannx php --version shows: PHP 7.0.27

Comment: Wow, by default even the CentOS 7 official software package repositories have PHP 5.4. Seems something got mixed up when you installed the other PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `.bash_profile` and modify the `PATH` with :

```
export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin:$PATH
```

then reload with :

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

More info [here](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#using-a-custom-php-binary).